# I Can't find my RMSProp implementation bug?

Tags: backpropagation, implementation, c++

I'm trying to implement **RMSProp** in my own Neural Network library so I can undertand the 'under-the-hood' operations, but this specific implementation is not working / converging, and I can't figure out why. 
I'm pretty sure I followed the [formula](https://medium.com/100-days-of-algorithms/day-69-rmsprop-7a88d475003b) (RMSProp + Momentum), and here is my code :

```
//Step 1 - Compute a hidden neuron (this == ClNeuron) error gradient (TanH)
double tmpBuffer = 0.00;
for (std::size_t i = 0; i<this->m_output_connections.size(); i++)
{
    ClNeuron* target_neuron = (ClNeuron*)m_output_connections[i]->m_target_neuron;
    tmpBuffer += (target_neuron->m_error_gradient * this->m_output_connections[i]->m_weight);
}

//Get the TanH derivative of this neuron's last output
this->m_error_gradient = tmpBuffer * this->TanHDerivative(this->m_result_buffer);




//Step 2 - For each of this neuron's input weights, compute the new weight's change
for(std::size_t i=0;i<this->m_input_connections.size();i++)
{
    double new_weight_delta = this->m_input_connections[i]->m_learning_rate * this->m_error_gradient * this->m_input_connections[i]->m_data;
    this->m_input_connections[i]->m_last_error_gradient_mean_square = 0.9 * this->m_input_connections[i]->m_last_error_gradient_mean_square + (1 - 0.9) * (new_weight_delta * new_weight_delta);
    this->m_input_connections[i]->m_momentum = this->m_input_connections[i]->m_momentum_constant * this->m_input_connections[i]->m_momentum + this->m_input_connections[i]->m_learning_rate * new_weight_delta / std::sqrt(this->m_input_connections[i]->m_last_error_gradient_mean_square)+0.000000001;

    //Make the actual weight update
    this->m_input_connections[i]->m_weight -= this->m_input_connections[i]->m_momentum;
}
```

Would anyone be kind enough to point me in the right direction ?
Many thanks !!